# After trying all solutions still facing - system.property org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot instantiate class

Tags: selenium

I am getting above error (`org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot instantiate class`) while running my first TestNG program. I have already gone through all the solutions but still issue persists.

I have already downloaded ChromeDriver, set it's correct path in class by using syste.property. Added required jars also. I have set system.setproprty() for chrome Driver, still gettimg the same error. Do I need to add any specific dependency in pom.xml or need to add main() in class?

Below is my class: My question is not getting posted due to less content explanation even thouguh I have written a lot, so adding this also. Parden me for this.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

/**
* Unit test for simple App.
*/
public class AppTest {
/**
* Create the test case
*
* @param testName
* name of the test case
*/


public AppTest(String testName) {
        super();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/Dell/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
}



// public static void main()
// {
//
// }

public WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
String appUrl = "https://google.com";

@Test
public void gmailLogin() {
    // launch the fire fox browser and open the application url
    driver.get(appUrl);
    System.out.println("Suceessfully opened the browser URL");

    // maximize the browser window
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    // declare and initialize the variable to store the expected title of
    // the web page.
    String expectedTitle = "Sign in - Google Accounts";

    // fetch the title of the web page and save it into a string variable
    String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedTitle, actualTitle);

    // enter a valid user name in the email text box
    WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("Email"));
    username.clear();
    username.sendKeys("TestSelenium");

    // enter a valid password in the password text box
    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd"));
    password.clear();
    password.sendKeys("password123");

    // click on the Sign in button
    WebElement SignInButton = driver.findElement(By.id("signIn"));
    SignInButton.click();

    // close the web browser
    driver.close();
    }

}
```

Below are the error logs: I have set `System.setProperty()` for chrome Driver, still getting the same error. Do I need to add any specific dependency in pom.xml or need to add main() in class?

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class com.selenium.SampleDemo1.AppTest
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:30)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:423)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:336)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:190)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:81)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:73)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:38)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:389)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:271)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:241)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:192)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:33)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:66)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:713)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:260)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:24)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
```

I have set system.setproprty() for chrome Driver, still gettimg the same error. Do I need to add any specific dependency in pom.xml or need to add main() in class?I have set system.setproprty() for chrome Driver, still gettimg the same error. Do I need to add any specific dependency in pom.xml or need to add main() in class?

Comment: Looks like either the path to the `chromedriver.exe` is INVALID or there are some permission issues. Can you please try the following:
1. Open up a command prompt and paste `C:/Users/Dell/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe`. You should see a chromedriver exe spun off. If that doesn't happen, then the path is the problem.
2. Why dont you just add `C:/Users/Dell/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe` to your `PATH` environment variable? That would get rid of this problem once and for all and you dont need to keep using the `System.setProperty()` all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The **AppTest** constructor method where you are setting the system property for chrome driver is not being invoked during execution as per the current code. You can add a new `setUpAppTest` method with **@BeforeClass** annotation, so that, the system property can be set for chrome before initializing the chrome driver, as shown below:

```
@BeforeClass
public void setUpAppTest(String testName) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/Dell/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
}
```

You will have to import `org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass` in order to use **BeforeClass**. Additionally, I would suggest you to use `driver.quit();` instead of `driver.close();` to ensure proper clean-up of webdriver instance.

Comment: Can you call super() like this from any instance method ?

Comment: `AppTest` is a constructor, where we can invoke the superclass constructor. In this particular case, making call to super class constructor does not seems to add any value, as there is no superclass defined for `AppTest`, hence it will invoke the default Object class constructor. However, I just realized that we cannot use @BeforeClass with constructor method, hence correcting the code. Thanks @cruisepandey for your inputs.

Comment: My next question was this  one "Can we use @BeforeClass on constructor"?  May be OP has missed to extends the current class.

Comment: We cannot use @BeforeClass on constructor, hence I suggested to use a new set-up method.

Comment: OP has constructor with him, he needs to clarify the things. Well I was aware of `We cannot use @BeforeClass on constructor`

Answer (score 0):

I see few issues with the way above method is implemented. Above code is more of the sequential flow where you are defining the initialization in later part of the code, hence you are seeing the above exception.

1. Try to have a superclass where initialization of the drivers, system property are required to run the test cases. For example: (Define a driver class like below)

> ```
> public class OnUIStart{
>  protected void starting(Description description) {
>         super.starting(description);
>         if (!DriverManager.INSTANCE.getDriver().isDriverStarted()) {
>             String testBrowser = System.getenv("TEST_BROWSER");
>             BrowserType browserType;
>             if (!StringUtils.isBlank(testBrowser)) {
>                 browserType = BrowserType.valueOf(testBrowser.toUpperCase());
>             } else {
>                 browserType = BrowserType.CHROME;
>             }
>             DriverManager.INSTANCE.setDriverConfiguration(getDriverConfiguration(browserType));
>             DriverManager.INSTANCE.startDriver();
>             String url = LocalConfig.INSTANCE.getUrlWithProtocol();
>             ChangeResolution.setDesktop();
>             log.info("URL: " + url);
>             DriverManager.INSTANCE.get(url);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

With the above code you can set all the system properties and initialization required. Make sure you have proper modularization of the methods which you defining.

2. In your test case

> ```
> public class testClass extends OnUIStart {
> }
> ```

Above implementation make sure all the initialization happening properly.